# getting image id from ImageAdapter

Tags: android, image, gridview, imageview

I'am new to android and I've a project of making a grid view of images and onclick on image it shows it , thats the ImageAdapter class code

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Activity activity;

    private String mode = "";

    int[] images=null ;

    public ImageAdapter(Activity act, String mode , int[] images){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        activity = act;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.images= images ;
    }

    public ImageView getImage(int pos)
    {
        ImageView im = (ImageView) getItem(pos);
        return im ;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return new Integer(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("grid")){
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_image1, null);
            }
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            iv.setImageResource(images[position]);
        } else if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("gallery")){
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_image_gallery, null);
            }
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            iv.setImageResource(images[position]);
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

thats my grid activity

```
public class GridActivity extends Activity {


    GridView grid = null;
    public static ImageAdapter adapter1 ;
    public static ImageAdapter adapter2 ;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid);
        adapter1= new ImageAdapter(GridActivity.this, "grid" , Images.images1);
        adapter2 = new ImageAdapter(GridActivity.this, "grid" , Images.images2);

          Intent i = this.getIntent();
        if (i!=null)
        {
        String unique = i.getExtras().getString("Unique");
        if (unique.equals("islam"))

                {
        Toast.makeText(GridActivity.this, "islam", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter1);

                }
        if (unique.equals("natural"))   
        {
            Toast.makeText(GridActivity.this, "nat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


             grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
             grid.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }

        }

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(GridActivity.this, imgPrevActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("selectedIntex", pos);
                startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(GridActivity.this,"ddd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the activity where it supposes to show any clicked on image

```
public class imgPrevActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.each_image1);
        ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        int pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("selectedIntex");

        // ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(imgPrevActivity.this, "image prev", null);

       long Id= GridActivity.adapter1.getItemId(pos);
       im.setImageResource((int) Id);

    }

}
```

i've tried to get the position of image clicked on from the grid
then getting the Id from the position
and setting the image view to that ID

but it doesnt work !!

thats where the images are put in arrays

```
public class Images {

    public static int[] images1 = {
        R.drawable.buds, R.drawable.cherry_34,
        R.drawable.clouds_2, R.drawable.coffee_beans_2,
        R.drawable.death_valley_sand_dunes
        };

    public static int[] images2= {
        R.drawable.morning_glory_pool,
        R.drawable.pink_flowers, R.drawable.sun_flower,
        R.drawable.sunrise_3, R.drawable.yellow_rose_3,



    };





}
```

Comment: what do you mean by but it doesnt work !! any error ??

Comment: @Tanimreja 
shows nothing .. blank activity

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your image resource id with intent. The list item id of adapter is useless because you have new Activity on the screen.

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(GridActivity.this, imgPrevActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("selectedIntex", grid.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
            startActivity(i);

            Toast.makeText(GridActivity.this,"ddd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

and change your code in your ImgPreviewActivity:

```
public class imgPrevActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.each_image1);
    ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("selectedIntex", 0);
    im.setImageResource(pos);
}
```

}

I think it should work